# No warnings for headers included by headers in non-current directories

Tags: c, gcc, clang, compiler-flags

How can I let gcc and clang generate warnings for header files included by header files in non-current directories?
I'm using gcc 4.9.2 and clang 3.6.0.

For example, assume that `./include_a.c` includes `./dir/a.h`, `./dir/a.h` includes `./b.h`, and `./b.h` is expected to generate a warning for `-Wconversion`; then, gcc and clang with `-Wconversion` DO NOT generate the expected warning when they compile `include_a.c`. With `-Wconversion -Wsystem-headers`, the expected warning is generated, but it often comes with many useless warnings for system headers. When `./b.h` is directly included from a source file in the current directory (such as `./include_b.c`), the expected warning is generated without `-Wsystem-headers`.

The following shell script reproduces this example (the case of clang is omitted):

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir dir
echo '#include "b.h"'                    >dir/a.h
echo 'void f() {int a = 0; char b = a;}' >b.h

echo '#include "dir/a.h"' >include_a.c
echo '#include "b.h"'     >include_b.c

set -x

gcc -c include_a.c -Wconversion                  # DOES NOT generate a warning
gcc -c include_a.c -Wconversion -Wsystem-headers # generate a warning
gcc -c include_b.c -Wconversion                  # generate a warning
```

Output:

```
+ gcc -c include_a.c -Wconversion
+ gcc -c include_a.c -Wconversion -Wsystem-headers
In file included from dir/a.h:1:0,
                 from include_a.c:1:
./b.h: In function ‘f’:
./b.h:1:31: warning: conversion to ‘char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
 void f() {int a = 0; char b = a;}
                               ^
+ gcc -c include_b.c -Wconversion
In file included from include_b.c:1:0:
b.h: In function ‘f’:
b.h:1:31: warning: conversion to ‘char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
 void f() {int a = 0; char b = a;}
                               ^
```

This behavior seems not to be a bug because gcc and clang perform in the same way, but how can I obtain warnings from all the my source files?

Comment: When running your script I get am error for the first gcc invokation: dir/a.h:1:15: fatal error: b.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @esm Thank you for your quick response. I checked `$C_INCLUDE_PATH` and found that it ends with `:`, which unintentionally specifies a current directory as a include path. This value lets the compilers consider headers in the current directory to be system headers. I added `-I.` as a compiler option and got warnings properly. (This question is solved)